# Electron: write within the app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have an Electron build where I have put my app in `Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app`

Everything works fine. When I try to write a file (for instance with `fs.writeFileSync`) within the app root iteself (`Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app` directory) I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: EACCESS: permission denied
```

I made sure that the directory is writable. I can write everywhere else (for instance in `/tmp`). Since I need the app to modify some files of the app itself (for update reasons), what's wrong in what I'm trying to do? How to overwrite app files?

Comment: Do you mind showing the directory's permissions? Maybe you can't access this folder because of parents folders (Contents, Resources)?

Comment: To be sure this is not a permission problem, I've run chmod -R a+w Electron.app to give every directory and every file writing permissios

Comment: You need execution permission in order to go through directories (see this [post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/do-the-parent-directorys-permissions-matter-when-accessing-a-subdirectory)). Can you check this?

Comment: After chmod -R a+x Electron.app I get the very same error

Comment: I would check which is the user which has permissions. I came across a similar situation, though in linux, where the app folder was created by root and thus root had permissions  and the app which ran under a different user profile did not have permissions to write.